# Perl: kill a process that has the same name of another one

Tags: perl, kill

I have 2 process that use the same name and inside each process I'd like to insert a line which kill only 1 process. For example if the name of my 2 processes is "test" I can't insert into the file "test" a line like this :
system("killall -9 test");

because both processes will stop. How I can do it?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to kill the _other_ process with the same name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify each process via its process id, and kill using that. The process id *uniquely* identifies a process (not surprisingly!)

Note also that it's bad practise to use a -9 (`SIGKILL`) by default. A normal kill (`SIGINT`) will allow the process to catch this, perform any cleanup and then exit. A `SIGKILL` (-9) doesn't allow that cleanup opportunity and should be used as a last resort.